# How can i remove a button and its functionality for a speciic browser such as firefox but i want to it as remain on chrome?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove this button and its functionality for Firefox and Safari, but not on Chrome

```html
<button id="start" class="left tooltipped" data-tooltip="Record" style="padding: 16px;border-radius: 100%;position: relative;background: #EB455F;top: 12px;"></button>
```

Comment: We need a bit of info around "why" to be able to give you a sensible answer.

Comment: You can use CSS for this. Add `display:none` when the browser is Firefox or Safari.

Comment: What did you try for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi You can detect the browser and add a class to your button or remove the button and functionality.
Working Example: https://codepen.io/sethuramancbe/pen/abRBmGd

```
function fnBrowserDetect(){
                 
         let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
         let browserName;
         
         if(userAgent.match(/chrome|chromium|crios/i)){
             browserName = "chrome";
           }else if(userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)){
             browserName = "firefox";
           }  else if(userAgent.match(/safari/i)){
             browserName = "safari";
           }else if(userAgent.match(/opr\//i)){
             browserName = "opera";
           } else if(userAgent.match(/edg/i)){
             browserName = "edge";
           }else{
             browserName="No browser detection";
           }
         
          return browserName;       
  }

const browser = fnBrowserDetect();


const btn = document.getElementById('start');
const hideIn = ['firefox', 'safari'];
if (hideIn.includes(browser)) {
  btn.classList.add("hide");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `regular expression` to match any instance of "Firefox/" in the user agent string.
This will match all versions of Firefox, regardless of the operating system or other details of the user agent string.

```
// Check if the browser is Firefox
if (/Firefox\//.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  // Remove the button and its functionality
  var button = document.getElementById("start");
  button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
}
```